# Using Jenkins API token without Username

Tags: authentication, jenkins, token, jenkins-api

Is Jenkins has token mechanism to authorize Jenkins APIs without using username?

Thanks,
Srikanth.

Answer (score 0):

[Token without password](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=753720#content/view/10059793) supported since version 1.426

> API token is new since 1.426
>
> The API token is available in your personal configuration page
>
> Specifying the real password is still supported after 1.426, but it is not recommended

Comment: I'm looking for authenticating Jenkins API with some token without username.